# Pivot MySQL Table Using date as Column Name

Tags: mysql, pivot

How can I get this table
[image]

to look like this something like this.
[image]

Here's the table definition and Sample Data.

```
CREATE TABLE `result`  (
      `universal_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `flag` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `measurement` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `units` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `reference_range` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `value_conv` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `unit_conv` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `ref_conv` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `test_code` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `order_no` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `sample_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `test_group` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `date` datetime(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `patient_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `instrument` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `his_code` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `his_mainid` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `section` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `sub_section` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `print_status` int(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
      INDEX `SampleID`(`sample_id`) USING BTREE,
      INDEX `Section`(`section`) USING BTREE,
      INDEX `SubSection`(`sub_section`) USING BTREE,
      INDEX `TestCode`(`test_code`) USING BTREE,
      INDEX `Machine`(`instrument`) USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 463617 CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;

INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('White Blood Cells', '', '7.99', 'x10^9/L', '4.00-10.00', '8.0', 'x10^9/L', '4.0-10.0', 'WBC', 107649, 4, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Red Blood Cells', '', '5.24', 'x10^12/L', '3.50-5.50', '5.24', 'x10^12/L', '3.50-5.50', 'RBC', 107650, 3, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Hemoglobin', '', '14.1', 'g/L', '11.00-15.00', '14.1', 'g/L', '110-150', 'HGB', 107651, 1, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Hematocrit', '', '0.41', 'vol%', '0.37-0.47', '0.41', 'vol%', '0.37-0.47', 'HCT', 107652, 2, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('MCV', 'L', '78.1', 'fL', '80.00-96.00', '78.1', 'fL', '80-96', 'MCV', 107653, 11, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('MCH', 'L', '26.9', 'pg', '27.00-33.00', '26.9', 'pg', '27-33', 'MCH', 107654, 12, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('MCHC', '', '34.5', 'g/L', '33.40-35.50', '34.5', 'g/L', '33-36', 'MCHC', 107655, 13, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Platelet Count', '', '224,000', 'x10^3/uL', '100000.00-300000.00', '224', 'x10^3/uL', '100,000-300,000', 'PLT', 107656, 5, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Neutrophils', '', '0.58', '', '0.50-0.70', '0.6', '', '1-1', 'NEU_P', 107657, 6, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Lymphocytes', '', '0.36', '', '0.20-0.40', '0.4', '', '0-0', 'LYM_P', 107658, 9, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Monocytes', '', '0.06', '', '0.03-0.12', '0.1', '', '0-0', 'MON_P', 107659, 10, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Eosinophils', 'L', '0.00', '', '0.01-0.05', '0.0', '', '0-0', 'EOS_P', 107660, 7, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Basophils', '', '0.00', '', '0.00-0.01', '0.0', '', '0-0', 'BAS_P', 107661, 8, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:22:47', '271489', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC', 1);

INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('White Blood Cells', '', '28.04', 'x10^9/L', '', '28.0', 'x10^9/L', '', 'WBC', 107664, 4, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Red Blood Cells', '', '5.18', 'x10^12/L', '', '5.18', 'x10^12/L', '', 'RBC', 107665, 3, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Hemoglobin', '', '17.7', 'g/L', '', '17.7', 'g/L', '', 'HGB', 107666, 1, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Hematocrit', '', '0.50', 'vol%', '', '0.50', 'vol%', '', 'HCT', 107667, 2, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('MCV', '', '96.1', 'fL', '', '96.1', 'fL', '', 'MCV', 107668, 11, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('MCH', '', '34.2', 'pg', '', '34.2', 'pg', '', 'MCH', 107669, 12, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('MCHC', '', '35.5', 'g/L', '', '35.5', 'g/L', '', 'MCHC', 107670, 13, '0006261', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Platelet Count', '', '258,000', 'x10^3/uL', '', '258', 'x10^3/uL', '', 'PLT', 107671, 5, '0006265', 'Complete Blood Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Neutrophils', '', '0.80', '', '', '0.8', '', '', 'NEU_P', 107672, 6, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Lymphocytes', '', '0.13', '', '', '0.1', '', '', 'LYM_P', 107673, 9, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Monocytes', '', '0.06', '', '', '0.1', '', '', 'MON_P', 107674, 10, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Eosinophils', '', '.01', '', '', '0.0', '', '', 'EOS_P', 107675, 7, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('Basophils', '', '0.00', '', '', '0.0', '', '', 'BAS_P', 107676, 8, '0006261', 'Differential Count', '2021-04-14 05:24:18', '271472', NULL, 'Other_Test', NULL, NULL, 'Hematology', 'CBC+BType', 1);
```

This is the query that I used.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CAST(CONCAT('IFNULL((CASE WHEN `date` = ''', `date`, ''' THEN `measurement` END), NULL) AS ', `date`, '') AS CHAR)
     )INTO @sql
FROM
    `result` ORDER BY `date` DESC;
    
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT patient_id, universal_id AS `Parameter`, ', CAST(@sql as CHAR), ' 
                                    FROM result 
                                     GROUP BY universal_id ORDER BY order_no');
                                     
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Thank you!

Comment: The first images is unreadable can you add as text please.

Comment: Thank you for noticing sir, i just transferred it to excel. I hope it is readable now.

Comment: To provide a solution we need to test it. To test it we need to create and populate tables. Please provide table definitions and data as text. See DBfiddle and give a link?

Comment: I've added table definition and sample data I hope this helps. Thanks @Kendel

Comment: Are you using MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: @ardiepagulayan https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-create-pivot-table-in-mysql/ has an example of how to do a pivot table. In your case, you will have to build a query dynamically like so: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: Im using Mysql 8.x

Comment: @ardiepagulayan can you type your answer so that others can benefit from your knowledge? After you add your answer, accept your own answer so that viewers know that your question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review the links then was send in the comment with some tweaks, I had it to work. Here's the code that i used for future reference.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delta_check`(IN PID VARCHAR(50), IN Section VARCHAR(50), IN SubSection VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SET @PID = PID;
    SET @Section = Section;
    SET @SubSection = SubSection;
    
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
    
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(CONCAT("MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%y-%m-%d %H:%i') = '", DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%y-%m-%d %H:%i'), "' THEN `measurement` END) AS `", DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%y-%M-%d %H:%i'), "`") AS CHAR)) FROM result WHERE `patient_id` = PID AND section = Section AND sub_section = SubSection INTO @sql;
    
    SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT result.universal_id AS Parameter, specimen.si_unit AS Unit, reference_range.si_range, result.test_code AS `TestCode`, ", @sql, ", result.`section` AS Section, result.`sub_section` AS SubSection
                                        FROM result 
                                        LEFT JOIN specimen ON result.test_code = specimen.test_code
                                        LEFT JOIN reference_range ON result.test_code = reference_range.test_code
                                        WHERE result.`patient_id` = ? AND result.section = ? AND result.sub_section = ? GROUP BY result.test_code ORDER BY specimen.order_no ASC");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @PID, @Section, @SubSection;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Cheers you all for the help.

Thank you!